# Find where the function $k(x):=|\sin(x)|$ is differentiable and calculate its derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Find where the function$$k(x):=|\sin(x)|$$ is differentiable and calculate its derivative.

I have started, by trying to make a function by parts, because of the absolute value, getting this:
$$k(x):=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 & \sin (x)& x>0 \\ 
 & (-1) \sin (x) &  x<0\\ 
 & 0 & x=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I have my doubts abut writing for $x=0$, but i really dont know hoy to do this excersice, can someone explain me and tell me how to write it correctly?

The graph is like this:
[image]

Comment: Try drawing a graph of the function.

Comment: I'd recommend starting by graphing sine over a few periods, and then reflecting all the parts of the graph that are below the $x$-axis about the $x$-axis (giving you a graph entirely above the $x$-axis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|x|'=x/|x|\iff x\neq0$, it follows that $f'(x)=\dfrac{\sin(x)}{|\sin(x)|}\cdot\cos(x)\iff x\notin \pi\boldsymbol{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that R = A U B U C , where:

A = U A(n), A(n) = (n*pi, (n+1)*pi), n is : even ( read: union of the A(n)'s )

B = U B(n), B(n) = (n*pi, (n+1)*pi), n is: odd

C = { k*pi: k is an integer }.

Then observe that K(x) = sin(x) if x is in A, and - sin(x) if x is in B, and 0 if x is in C.

It is easy to check that K'(x) does not exist at x in C, and that K'(x) = cos(x) for x in A

, and K'(x) = -cos(x) for x in B.